# Typescript Error code: 2366, Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, server, typescript-generics

I am currently working on the server/database of my project. It is currently composed of Javascript, Typescript, MongoDB, Apollo-Server, and Express. The error above keeps coming up and I am not sure how to solve it. Here is the code I have on my index.ts file for my database folder.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import { Database, Listing, Booking, User } from '../lib/types';


const url = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net`;

export const connectDatabase = async (): Promise<Database> => {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const db = client.db("main");

    return {
      bookings: db.collection<Booking>("bookings"),
      listings: db.collection<Listing>("listings"),
      users: db.collection<User>("users"),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't handle errors, don't catch them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're catching the error but then you're not returning anything from the function. That is why it's complaining. Either remove the try/catch and handle the error in the function calling this one or return something usable to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Set `"noImplicitReturns"` to `false` in  `tsconfig.json`.